# Super Slow Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, performance

Well lately my 11.10 has been incredibly slow and I don't know why. Like everything is always really slow. Moving Windows across the screen or minimizing/maximizing is extremely slow. I don't know if the animations or what, it's just miserably slow. This was not happening in Windows7.

Comment: please tell about your installation type and hardware details

Comment: Sounds like a graphics driver issue. What video card do you have? If using nvidia, please run the [terminal command](http://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969) `lspci -d10de: -vvnn` and add the output to your question.

Comment: Could you post the output of `free -t -m` when your system is slow? And could you tell us, if there are high %CPU numbers with `ps -eo pcpu,args | sort -k 1 -r | head -10` (you don't have to post that output if you don't want, just if there are high numbers).

Comment: Yeah, same here. My advice would be to just stick with 11.04 until 12.04 comes out.

Comment: if anything update the graphics drivers, decrase swap usage and use a lighter desktop environment like lxde.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/39050/how-can-i-speed-up-unity-in-ubuntu-11-04-natty/39976#39976

Comment: Isn't it the case by any chance? http://askubuntu.com/questions/70995/desktop-runs-very-slick-animations-are-all-fast-and-flawless-moving-windows-ar